# Unable to compile Rust SQLx with postgres feature

Tags: rust

If I try to use `postgres` feature of SQLx Rust as follows,

```
[dependencies]
sqlx = { version = "0.3.3", default-features=false , features=["runtime-async-std", "macros", "postgres", "all-type"] }
```

Then I get a compilation error as follows

```
   Compiling sqlx-core v0.3.4
error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'matches_macro'
  --> /Users/asnimpansari/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/sqlx-core-0.3.4/src/postgres/value.rs:78:12
   |
78 |         if matches!(self.data, Some(PgData::Binary(_))) {
   |            ^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: for more information, see https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/65721

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `sqlx-core`.
```

Instead, if I use `mysql` instead `postgres` the build succeeds.

```
➜  ~ rustc  -V
rustc 1.41.1 (f3e1a954d 2020-02-24)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLx only supports the most recent version of Rust. As of April 14th 2020 that would be 1.42.0, which was released on March 9th.

This specific error is because the `matches!` macro was [stabilized in 1.42](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/03/12/Rust-1.42.html#matches)